# WPF image leap over another

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net

How to make this with XAML?

http://img851.imageshack.us/img851/8505/85612476.png

That are three images, one left, one right and one over both. I need to use panel that is not canvas.

Comment: What kind of Panel do you mean?

Comment: any kind that will work: grid or dockpanel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Image Width="250" Height="500" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    <Image Width="250" Height="500" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
    <Image Width="250" Height="250" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```